# mysql - insert multiple values for single column

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data into MySQL with multiple values in one field and remaining fields contains only one value.

I have tried below query

```
INSERT INTO assessment_training(
  PARENT_SLNO
  RNO
  TRAINING_CATEGORY
  TRAINING_NAME
) 
VALUES (
  9,
  1,
  'Technical',
  (1,7)
);
```

Error #1241

```
`INSERT INTO assessment_training(PARENT_SLNO,RNO,TRAINING_CATEGORY,TRAINING_NAME) VALUES (9,1,'Technical',(1,7))    Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
```

Comment: Reead about normalization

Comment: what is the datatype for this column? And in DB when the value of one column can be broken down into more than one value, you should consider splitting the column into two or more columns

Comment: Data type `VARCHAR()` is used. i want to split into same row by separating with coma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()`

```
INSERT INTO assessment_training(
  PARENT_SLNO,
  RNO,
  TRAINING_CATEGORY,
  TRAINING_NAME
) 
VALUES (
  9,
  1,
  'Technical',
  CONCAT("1", ",", "7")
);
```

Comment: need to give concat dynamically